# GUI designer for html/css that works well with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If such an application exists on Java, even better.

Comment: Does it has an html/css designer?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular is Netbeans - free, good IDE, and available on many platforms. Also very tied into the Java platform... so you might kill two birds with one stone.

http://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html

---

EDIT:

I played around with JetBrain's RubyMine - it's pretty awesome.

http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html

There's always Vim or Notepad++ though as well if you are a purist and love the retro-no-bs-only-me-and-my-editor thing.

That answer your question well enough?